# Extracting data from a fetch() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple fetch request like this:

```
 fetch('/data', {method: 'POST', credentials: 'same-origin', body: {'name': 'alice'}}).then(function(response){
        console.log('reply:');

        console.log(response);
    });
```

Basically it should send a POST request to the local address /data with some parameters in it (same thing as an HTML form does) and then return the reply it gets (the /data page simply prints out "this is a test response")

But when I look at the `console.log(response);` it looks like this:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: ".../data", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }
```

The actual string returned by the page /data ("this is a test response") is nowhere to be found.

So how can I retrieve the actual returned string then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the **body** of the response, you need to actually do that. See the details on MDN ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)), but in brief, if you want the body as text, then:

```
fetch(/*...*/)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(responseText) {
        // ...
    });
```